# What is the null hypothesis in R's t.test() if alternative is not 'two-sided'

Tags: r, t-test

recently I wondered about the correct formulation of the null hypothesis in R's `t.test()` function for One-Sample-tests.

Let's assume our known population mean a is 0.3:

H<sub>0</sub>: μ = a; H<sub>a</sub>: μ ≠ a :

```
t.test(rnorm(100, 0, 1), alternative = "two.sided", mu=0.3)
```

H<sub>0</sub>: μ < a; H<sub>a</sub>: μ > a :

```
t.test(rnorm(100, 0, 1), alternative = "greater", mu=0.3)
```

H<sub>0</sub>: μ > a; H<sub>a</sub>: μ < a :

```
t.test(rnorm(100, 0, 1), alternative = "less", mu=0.3)
```

Are the hypotheses correctly specified?

Comment: No. Your null is always mu = a. The rest is correct.

Comment: To elaborate, see e.g. the example and discussion given [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/faq/general/tail_tests.htm).

Comment: Well technically your H0 when alternative is "greater" is u <= a, and when alternative is "less", then you have H0: u>= a. But I guess the results will be the same, because the whole thing is continuous...

Comment: @ira That's not correct. H0 does not change, the "sidedness" defines the direction in which you consider evidence against the null (conditional on the null being true).

Comment: @MauritsEvers Can you provide a verbal conclusion one has to draw if for example the H0 is rejected for `alternative = "greater"` and if one fails to reject the hypothesis? But for the `ks.test()` function the H0 changes depending on the chosen parameter value for 'alternative'?

Comment: @MauritsEvers No, that is just a matter of notation. For one sided test (say, alternative = greater), you compare the alternative to the Null, that you mean is less or equal to certain value. For two sided, you use the null that mean is equal to something, alternative is that the mean is different.

Comment: @ira I disagree. A different null corresponds to a different hull hypothesis test. In the current null hypothesis significance testing paradigm, a specific null hypothesis (mu = a) is pitted against a less specific (and often deliberately vague) alternative hypothesis (e.g. mu != a, mu > a, mu < a). If you change the null, you perform a different test, the sidedness characterises your alternative.

Comment: @CarstenOppitz I'm not sure I understand what what you mean by "verbal conclusion". Rejecting H0 in a t-test with `alternative = "greater"` corresponds to you saying that it is very unlikely to get a t statistic *as large or larger* conditional on the null being true.

Comment: @MauritsEvers In case of a rejection of the `alternative = "greater"` : Something like "The hypothesis that the sample mean equals 'a' can be rejected with a certain probability and we can assume that our true sample mean is statistically significantly greater than 'a'." Is that conclusion correct?

Comment: @MauritsEvers I think I got the meaning this far...but can you confirm that the H0 indeed change for the Kolmogorov Smirnov `ks.test()`?

Comment: @CarstenOppitz Regarding your second-last comment: No your conclusion is not quite correct. Your p-value (of a one-sided or two-sided test) corresponds to the probability for seeing data (or more specifically, a data-derived statistic) as extreme or more (the sidedness determines the direction you’re looking in), *conditional on the null being true*. The p-value is *not* the probability for (or against) the null (or alternative) hypothesis. This is one of the common p-value fallacies/misinterpretations.

Comment: @CarstenOppitz And lastly, send me a private email if you like to get some additional reading material on null hypothesis significance testing, p-values, and their interpretation.